# Explain the basics dynamic and static

Tags: networking, wifi

I'm not entirely for sure on what my interfaces should look like

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two kinds of networks:

Networks where all sorts of devices connect. Not all devices are on all the time, and typically the devices don't need to communicate with each other. A home network is a typical example.

These networks have [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) server in the gateway (in your home network, the router). Devices connecting to it broadcast "hello, I'm new here, please give me a local Internet address", and then they get one. This is meant by *dynamic* IP assignment.

Then there are big networks in universities or companies, where there are always the same devices (or they change infrequently), and devices often need to communicate with each other (or the sysadmin needs to, at least). Then some central instance assigns them IP addresses, and configures them locally so they always get the same address. This is meant by *static* IP assignment.

There are middle grounds: You can configure your DHCP server in the router in your home network to always give the same IP address to same devices, e.g. your NAS storage. The company may have some devices with static addresses, and lots of "unimportant generic clients" that get a dynamic address. Etc.

In doubt you want dynamic address, and whatever operating system to use is configured out of the box to use the dynamic addresses it gets via DHCP. You don't have to do anything in the usual case.